# insert post & Upload post thumbnail from the front end using ajax

Tags: uploads, ajax, front-end, wp-insert-post, post-thumbnails

***i have searched & searched for an explenation and have found some answers
that seem to be working for other people on this topics but i havent been able to get working.***

**This is my "form"**

```
<div id="uploadPatternForm">
<div class="rightCol fleft w30 ml2">
    <h4><?php _e('Your Info', 'sagive'); ?></h4>
    <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Your Email" />
    <input type="text" name="senderWebsite" id="senderWebsite" placeholder="Your Website" />
    <input type="text" name="senderCountry" id="senderCountry" placeholder="Your Country" />
</div>
<div class="midCol fleft w30 ml2">
    <h4><?php _e('Pattern Info', 'sagive'); ?></h4>
    <input type="text" name="patternName" id="patternName" placeholder="Pattern Name" />
    <input type="file" name="patternImage" id="patternImage" size="14" placeholder="Upload Pattern" style="margin-bottom: 8px" />
    <textarea name="patternDesc" id="patternDesc" class="patternDesc" placeholder="Short Description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="leftCol fleft w30 ml2">
    <h4><?php _e('Pattern Usage', 'sagive'); ?></h4>
    <input type="checkbox" name="personalProjects" id="personalProjects" checked disabled /><span class="fs13 c99">Free in personal projects</span><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="commercialProjects" id="commercialProjects" checked /><span class="fs13 c99">Free in commercial projects</span> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="templatesYouSell" id="templatesYouSell" checked /><span class="fs13 c99">Free in templates you sell</span> <br />
    <div id="submitPattern" class="submitPattern"><?php _e('Upload Pattern', 'sagive'); ?></div>

    <input type="hidden" id="returnedId" value="" />
</div>
<div class="fix"></div>
<div id="pu_message"></div>
```

.
**This is My javascript file**

```
jQuery(function($){ 

// CALL FOR NEXT 3 FEATURED BUSINESS
$('div#submitPattern').click(function() {
        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'action_upload_pattern',
            sender_name: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('input#senderName').attr('value'),
            sender_email: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('input#senderEmail').attr('value'),
            sender_website: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('input#senderWebsite').attr('value'),
            sender_country: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('input#senderCountry').attr('value'),
            pattern_name: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('input#patternName').attr('value'),
            pattern_image: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('input#patternImage').attr('value'),
            pattern_desc: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('#patternDesc').attr('value'),
            pattern_terms_personal: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('#personalProjects').attr('value'),
            pattern_terms_commercial: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('#commercialProjects').attr('value'),
            pattern_terms_templates: $('div#uploadPatternForm').find('#templatesYouSell').attr('value')
        }, function(data) {
            var $response=$(data);
            var postid      = $response.filter('#postid').html();
            var success     = $response.filter('#success').html();
            var error       = $response.filter('#error').html();


            if(success) {
                // APPEND NRE ITEMS AND FADE IN SLOW    
                $('input#returnedId').val(postid);

                // APPEND NRE ITEMS AND FADE IN SLOW                
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('div#pu_message').fadeOut('fast');
                    $('div#pu_message').empty();
                    $('div#pu_message').append(success);                    
                    $('div#pu_message').fadeIn('slow');
                }, 500);
            }

        });

});
```

});

.
**This is my ajax php listener**

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-upload-pattern', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ajaxLoops/ajax-upload_pattern.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-upload-pattern', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl

add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_upload_pattern', 'ajax_action_upload_pattern' ); // ajax for logged in users
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_pattern', 'ajax_action_upload_pattern' ); // ajax for unlogged in users

function ajax_action_upload_pattern() {

$sender_name                =   $_POST['sender_name'];
$sender_email               =   $_POST['sender_email'];
$sender_website             =   $_POST['sender_website'];
$sender_country             =   $_POST['sender_country'];
$pattern_name               =   $_POST['pattern_name'];
$pattern_image              =   $_POST['pattern_image'];
$pattern_desc               =   $_POST['pattern_desc'];
$pattern_terms_personal     =   $_POST['pattern_terms_personal'];
$pattern_terms_commercial   =   $_POST['pattern_terms_commercial'];
$pattern_terms_templates    =   $_POST['pattern_terms_templates'];

/*** TESTING **
echo '
    <div id="success">
        <ul>
            <li>sender_name: '.$sender_name.'</li>
            <li>sender_email: '.$sender_email.'</li>
            <li>sender_website: '.$sender_website.'</li>
            <li>sender_country: '.$sender_country.'</li>
            <li>pattern_name: '.$pattern_name.'</li>
            <li>pattern_image: '.$pattern_image.'</li>
            <li>pattern_desc: '.$pattern_desc.'</li>
            <li>pattern_terms_personal: '.$pattern_terms_personal.'</li>
            <li>pattern_terms_commercial: '.$pattern_terms_commercial.'</li>
            <li>pattern_terms_templates: '.$pattern_terms_templates.'</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ';
*/


/****************************************
** INSER NEW POST
****************************************/
$title          =   $pattern_name;
$description    =   $pattern_desc;

$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => stripslashes($description),
    'post_status'   => 'pending',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_category' => array( 3 )
);

$postid     =   wp_insert_post($post, 10, 1);
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post', 10, 1); 


/****************************************
** UPDATE POST META FIELDS
****************************************/   

// SENDER DATA META FIELDS
update_metadata('post', $postid, '_cmb_pattern_author_name', $sender_name);

if($sender_website) {
    $noLinkAuthor = 'false'; 
    update_metadata('post', $postid, '_cmb_no_link_author', $sender_website);
}   

if($sender_website) {
    $noLinkAuthor = 'false'; 
    update_metadata('post', $postid, '_cmb_pattern_author_url', $sender_website);
}

// TERMS OF USE
update_metadata('post', $postid, '_cmb_terms_personal_projects', 'on');
if($pattern_terms_commercial == 'on') {update_metadata('post', $postid, '_cmb_terms_commercial_projects', 'on');}
if($pattern_terms_templates == 'on') {update_metadata('post', $postid, '_cmb_terms_resell_intemplates', 'on');}


        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($pattern_image) {
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $pattern_image, $postid );
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($postid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }   


echo '<div id="success">'.__('Pattern Uploaded!', 'sagive').'</div>';
echo '<div id="postid">'.$postid.'</div>';

die(); // stop executing script
}
```

.
I am trying to grab all the data... create a new post and then upload & attach the image uploaded as the post thumbnail.

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: No error.. i just dont know how to upload a file (and set it as thumbnail) using ajax... there is some process that needs to be done which i dont know / havent been able to duplicate.   

the file name is being transfered but not the file itself... i need some informtaion / example that works... 

tried some solutions offered in other answeres but havent been able to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get just the file names because you are not uploading the files. Uploading files using AJAX is currently not that easy. Newer browsers implement the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) interface, but for older browsers you're stuck with some kind of flash uploader, like [PlUpload](http://www.plupload.com/) for example.

I suggest you use PlUpload because it's bundled with WP, and send all your data together with the uploaded file. Also use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action to add javascript:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){

  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-upload-pattern', 
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-upload_pattern.js',
     array('plupload-all', 'jquery'),
     1.0
  );

  wp_localize_script('ajax-upload-pattern', 'ajax_object', 
     array(
       'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
     ));
});
```

In your HTML change the file input with:

```
<a id="browse_file" href="#"> Upload pattern </a>
```

Then your script would look something like this (I assume this is `ajax-upload_pattern.js`):

```
jQuery(function($){ 

  var myUploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    browse_button: 'browse_file', // id of the browser button
    multipart: true,              // <- this is important because you want
                                  //    to pass other data as well
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl 
  });

  myUploader.init();

  myUploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files){
    $('#browse_file').text('Selected: ' + files[0].name); 
    // do a console.log(files) to see what file was selected...
  });

  // before upload starts, get the value of the other fields
  // and send them with the file
  myUploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up) {
    myUploader.settings.multipart_params = {
      action: 'action_upload_pattern',
      // add your other fields here...    
    };
  });

  // equivalent of the your "success" callback
  myUploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, ret){   
    console.log(ret.response);  
  });

  // trigger submission when this button is clicked
  $('#submitPattern').on('click', function(e) {
    myUploader.start();
    e.preventDefault();      
  });

});
```

In your AJAX request handler function the sent data is available as usual in the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` superglobals:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_action_upload_pattern', function(){

  print_r($_POST);
  print_r($_FILES);

  // insert your post and link your file here...

  exit;
});
```

Comment: thank @onetrickpony  -  this only half works... 1st. i guess i dont know how to combine my js file with the script you present here. that results in 2 ajax calls which make it imposibble to attach the image to a post (no coherent post id).    -   can you show me how to mix my jquery code with the one you offered here plz?

Comment: You don't need two Ajax queries. PlUpload will fire the ajax request on which you can attach your other fields. Add them in the `BeforeUpload` event, just like I added the `action` field

Comment: i am sorry to be a "nudnik"... (Trust me - i am not lazy) i need some help with that - i tried that i am messing it up time after time. my knowledge using ajax is growing but i still cant see in my head what you mean... could you help me integrate your solution into my javascript code? - thats why i stated in my bounty that: "i need a complete answer using my code as an example."  -  again... sorry for the hassle. i just need to see it once to understand.

Comment: [Like this](http://codepad.org/pGTddaiw). The php should be obvious. Better ask what exactly you don't understand...

Comment: Worls like a charm mate! (fyi: i completly messed up the code so thanks for the extra effort) - would award you the bounty as soon as possible and thank you very much :)

Comment: This Shoots of ajax with every image (issuse with multiple images)... got of the top of your head a way to fix this mate?